# AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute '_current_application'

Tags: python, appium, python-appium

I am automating the pressKeyButton() in python.for this following is the code

```
from AppiumLibrary import AppiumLibrary

def PressKeyboardButton(self, buttonToPress):
    self._current_application().execute_script("var vKeyboard = target.frontMostApp().keyboard(); vKeyboard.buttons()['" + buttonToPress + "'].tap();");
```

After executing it, I have got the following exception:

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute '_current_application'
```

can anybody suggest me solution.

Comment: Well... there's no `self` because you're not in a class...!?

Comment: i have removed self from the arguments of the function,but i still have the same probem

Answer (score 0):

`PressKeyboardButton` is a function that is accept an argument named `self`, since it is causing error on `unicode` object, I'm assuming you are passing a unicode string as an argument to your function. String obviously doesn't have any `_current_application` attribute defined.

May be you are trying to use a class and mistaking function for a class, try something on these lines -

```
class KeyboardButton:

      def press(self, button):
          self._current_application().execute_script("var vKeyboard = target.frontMostApp().keyboard(); vKeyboard.buttons()['" + buttonToPress + "'].tap();");

      def _current_application(self):
          # add your code.
```

Or you could just use a function

```
from AppiumLibrary import AppiumLibrary

def PressKeyboardButton(self, buttonToPress):
    current_application().execute_script("var vKeyboard = target.frontMostApp().keyboard(); vKeyboard.buttons()['" + buttonToPress + "'].tap();")

def current_application():
    # your code.
```

Something on these lines, since it is not clear what you are trying to accomplish.